# Is there better way to access configs from Conroller plugin in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

Just need get some vals located in application.ini(main ini) in the Controller plugin
I know I can create an instance of Zend_config_Ini but would like to use the existing resource (application.ini is already used in Front Controller)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Zend Registry](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.registry.html)

```
// when loading the config
Zend_Registry::set('config', $config);
// later, somewhere
$config = Zend_Registry::get('config');
```

Comment: does Front Controller has it in zendRegistry?

Comment: I assume you have an application.ini that you load in the bootstrap and feed it to front controller. You can add it to the registry there and fetch it later. Please provide more info if different.

Comment: I strongly discourage using `Zend_Registry` for this. It's basically nothing else than using global variables.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getParam('bootstrap')->getOptions();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you now that you will need your configuration values from `application.ini` in few places around your whole application, you could read it up in bootstrap and store it in registry:

```
$appConfig = new Zend_Config_Ini('path/to/application.ini');
Zend_Registry::set('applicationConfig', $appConfig);
```

then later you can always access it:

```
Zend_Registry::get('applicationConfig')->someValue;
```

Comment: From the bootstrap, isn't `$this->getOptions()` the array version of the application.ini?

Comment: why would you duplicate my answer instead of comment ?

Comment: sorry, when I started typing my answer there were none and I didn't noticed yours while typing mine

Answer (score 0):

For reasons of testability and decoupling I would not use the `Zend_Registry` approach. In my opinion the plugin should not know anything about `Zend_Config`, but instead all options that are needed in the plugin should be injected from outside.

For example, if you want to use the config option "`MyOption`" in the Plugin `Controller_Plugin_MyPlugin` you could inject the needed parameters in the `Bootstrap` class as follows:

```
public function run()
{
    $sopPlugin = $this->getResource('frontcontroller')->getPlugin('Controller_Plugin_MyPlugin');
    $sopPlugin->setMyOption($this->getOption('MyOption'));
    parent::run();
}
```

The advantage is that with this solution you avoid dependencies to `Zend_Registry` (which in fact is just an euphemism for a global variable) in your plugin code.